# Ktor client unit test hangs / freezes within CoroutineScope.launch()

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm having an issue in my KMM project testing a ktor client request that is launched async within a new scope. For testing purposes I pass in `Dispatchers.Unconfined` as the context of the new scope (In actual production code I'm using `newSingleThreadContext()`).

I've created an extremely simplified version of the hanging ktor request below:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Test
fun testExample(): Unit {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
    scope.launch {
        val client = HttpClient { BrowserUserAgent() }

        // This line hangs
        val response : HttpResponse = client.get("https://google.com")

        // Will never get here
        println("Response: $response")
        fail("This test should fail")
    }
}
```

Note that if you don't call within the CoroutineScope.launch then it works fine. Then hang/ freeze only occurs when called within a CoroutineScope.launch. Again this is an extrememly simplified example, but in my actual code the reason have it setup this way is so that I can process some data in a background thread before ultimately making the ktor request - hence the CoroutineScope.launch. Also note that my code seems to work fine when running on an iOS simulator. **It only hangs when running as a unit test**.

Am I missing something to make this work, or is this a bug?

Comment: On my machine, your test passes using Ktor 1.6.4 or 1.6.5 on iosX64 and linuxX64 targets. Could you please describe the environment you run this test in?

Comment: For me the test passes as well, but thats not the issue. The issue is that the response never returns, and the line `println("Response: $response")` never prints. I've edited the code example to add a `fail()` statement so that the test case *should fail* - however on my machine it still passes. Running on MacOS with targets android and iosX64, ktor v1.6.5, kotlin v1.5.31, kotlinx-coroutines-core v1.5.2-native-mt.

Comment: That's expected behavior because the code in a block of `launch` is executed asynchronously. Since you don't explicitly wait for its completion, a response is never gets printed. In other words, your test completes its execution before a background job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me ended up being to run my tests within runBlocking() scope, and to inject its `coroutineContext` into my class to be used when running CoroutineScope.launch().

```
object RequestService {
  private val requestContext = newSingleThreadContext("request")
  var testContext by AtomicReference<CoroutineContext?>(null)

  fun makeRequest(block : () -> Unit) {
    CoroutineScope.launch(testContext ?: requestContext) {
      block()
    }
  }
}

@Test
fun testExample() = runBlocking {
    RequestService.testContext = this.coroutineContext
    RequestService.makeRequest() {
        println("Running Ktor coroutine test")
        val client = HttpClient { BrowserUserAgent() }

        // This line doesn't hang anymore when running within runBlocking coroutineContext
        val response : HttpResponse = client.get("https://google.com")
        println("Response: $response")
    }
    println("Finished running Ktor coroutine test")
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone else attempting to create a cross-platform testable service. Thanks [Aleksei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935799/ktor-client-unit-test-hangs-freezes-within-coroutinescope-launch#comment123688694_69935799) for comment helping me get there.